# scenekit - zoom in/out to selected node of scene

Tags: ios, scenekit

I have a scene in which a human body is displayed. I want to zoom in to a specific body part when a user taps on it.

I changed the position of the camera to the position of Node but it points not exactly on it.

Also I need to keep the selected part in center of the screen when zoom in.

How can I accomplish zoom in / out?

Comment: Are the different body parts different nodes or are the entire body an node?

Comment: They all exist in one node, they are subparts of a main node

Comment: That sounds contradicting. Are you saying they are child nodes inside a parent node?

Comment: Yes exactly they are child nodes

Comment: I would need to zoom in to the main body sub nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by moving the camera instead of scaling the Model. I got the tap point by Gesture Recognizer and similarly the point of touch.

Now I converted the View-Coordinates to Scene Coordinates

```
CGPoint p = [gestureRecognize locationInView:scnView];

    NSArray *hitResults = [scnView hitTest:p options:nil];

    SCNVector3 projectedOrigin = [scnView projectPoint:SCNVector3Zero];

    SCNVector3 vector = SCNVector3Make(p.x, p.y, projectedOrigin.z);

    SCNVector3 worldPoint = [scnView unprojectPoint:vector];
```

and then positioned the Camera to the worldPoint.

Comment: Can you please suggest how did you positioned the camera?

Answer (score 1):

To reposition it in a Z-axis you want to multiply the currents node matrix with the new matrix.

```
var node = childNode.transform
var translation = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(1.0, 1.0, adjustedZValue)
var newTrans = SCNMatrix4Mult(node, translation)
childNode.transform = newTrans
```

Edit: Had some names mixed up

Comment: It will just scale to sub node. I will try using scaling and positioning.

Answer (score 1):

a bit cleaned up and more "swifty":

```
let transform = childNode.transform
let adjustedZValue = Float32(3)
let translation = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(1.0, 1.0, adjustedZValue)
let newTrans = SCNMatrix4Mult(transform, translation)
childNode.transform = newTrans
```